# Can you export pen tool work path from Photoshop to After Effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, adobe-after-effects, pen-tool

Is it possible to export a pen tool work path from Adobe Photoshop to Adobe After Effects?

I know it's possible to export work paths to Illustrator but I just couldn't find a way to export it to Adobe After Effects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can copypaste between the applications.

Comment: how to do that??

Comment: @Mr.Tj select the vector with the arrow tool press ctrl/option + c to copy then go to AE and paste into a vector object

Comment: @Mr.Tj `Composition editor -> Right Mouse Button click -> New -> Solid...` -> `Select layer Solid` -> `Ctrl + V`(paste the selected path from Photoshop). This should create a mask on the layer in shape of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think no. Photoshop don't really do vector, it use "vector like" tools during the work but can't really export in vector files, in After Effect or not.
But you can import vector files (like illustrator files) in After effect (will be shape layers).

Comment: I tried importing the illustrator file to aw but it didn't work it just gave me a black screen in AE but no pen tool workpath

Answer (score 0):

Alright so, I have done some research and found that you can copy from Photoshop, illustrator, or even fireworks and paste in after effects of you need any help maybe try reading this whole article!
Thanks for trying to help!

Article:
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/creating-shapes-masks.html#copy_a_path_from_illustrator_photoshop_or_fireworks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get around this. you need to make a vector mask from the work path. right-click with a pen tool. a layer must be selected. unfortunately all open paths will be closed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try importing the `.PSD` file directly into the After Effects.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Photoshop

1. <kbd>Ctrl + Mouse</kbd> to select a path in Photoshop.
2. <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to copy the path to the clipboard

### 2. After Effects

1. Select a `Composition`
2. Right mouse click on the `Composition editor`
3. `New -> Shape layer`
4. `Shape Layer 1 -> Add -> Path`
5. Select `Shape Layer 1 -> Contents -> Path 1 -> Path`
6. <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> to paste the path to the layer property
7. `Shape Layer 1 -> Add -> Fill` to fill the shape with a color

---

For example:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]